# Querying subviews in Swift

Tags: jquery, ios, arrays, uikit, swift2

The line of code I am having a problem with is

```
if let buttons = self.viewWithTag(7) as! Button {
    buttons.backgroundColor = UIColor.MDColor.white
    buttons.title?.textColor = UIColor.MDColor.grey800
}
```

Earlier in the code I set an array of 42 of these object to have a tag of 7.  Later within a function I am trying to get all of those object and change some properties.  The issue I am having is the code doesn't query through all 42 of the views, I don't know if any are being changed.  I have also tried

```
if let buttons = self.viewWithTag(7) as? Button {
        if buttons.backgroundColor == self.accentColor {
            buttons.backgroundColor = UIColor.MDColor.white
            buttons.title?.textColor = UIColor.MDColor.grey800
        }

    }
```

I think a `for` loop like `for buttons in self` would work but the compiler comes back with `DatePicker` does not conform to protocol `SequenceType`.  Should I add `SequenceType` to the class?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to be.

```
let view = self.dialog?.subviews.filter({$0.tag == 1})
```

That dove down one layer, the view I wanted to change was two layers down.

To get the view I wanted was.

```
for button in view![0].subviews.filter({$0.tag == 7}) {
      let buttons = button as! Button
      buttons.backgroundColor = UIColor.MDColor.white
      buttons.title?.textColor = UIColor.MDColor.grey800
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you check the documentation, you'll se that `func viewWithTag(_ tag: Int) -> UIView?` returns one view with the tag, not all views. What I would do is create `IBOutletCollection` if you load the views from storyboard or just array of the views, like this:

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: [Button]! // for IBOutlet collection
// or
var buttons: [Button]!
```

then you just need to iterate through the array:

```
for button in buttons {
    if button.backgroundColor == self.accentColor {
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.MDColor.white
        button.title?.textColor = UIColor.MDColor.grey800
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work UIView still doesn't have sequence type.  To iterate over the views I need to use something like self.subviews.

Comment: Then maybe provide a code for what are you trying to achieve with said `DatePicker`. `UIView` isn't of sequence type, but array of `UIViews` is of `CollectionType` which is of type `SequenceType` ...

Comment: yeah I have added a for loop for views in self.subviews but still am lost.